# Woocommerce How to show all product catgories and there subcategories?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on product import using csv file. I need to show the list of all products first from csv and then need to show all categories from woocommerce. All categories and there subcategories are coming but i need to show them in multi check select box in hierarical order e.g

```
Clothes
 -- Jeans
 ------ Blue
 ------ Black 
 -- T-shirt
Jwellery 
  -- Diamond
  ------ Chain
  ------ Ring
  -- Gold
Phone
```

But all these are coming in single line. I am not able to find which is parent and child category.This is my code.Please help.

```
$args = array(
                       'hierarchical' => 1,
                       'show_option_none' => '',
                       'hide_empty' => 0,
                       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
                    );
                    $subcats = get_categories($args);
                    echo '<ul id="test" class="test">';
                      foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
                        $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
                        if($sc->category_parent == 0) 
                        {
                            echo '<li><input type="checkbox"  name="product_cat[]" value="'.$sc->name.'"/><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';  
                        }else
                        { 
                            echo '<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"  name="product_cat[]" value="'.$sc->name.'"/><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
                        } 
                      }
                    echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code brother

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
    'parent'        => false, // get top level categories
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    //'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hierarchical'  => 1,
   'show_option_none' => '',
     'hide_empty' => false,
);

$categories = get_categories( $args );
echo "<ul>";
foreach ( $categories as $category ){
    $link=get_category_link( $category->term_id );
    echo "<label><a href=".$link."><input type=checkbox value=". $category->name . " name=". $category->name . ">". $category->name ."</a>" ."</label>";

    $sub_args = array(
        'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
        'parent'        => $category->term_id, // get child categories
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        //'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hierarchical'  => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    );

    $sub_categories = get_categories( $sub_args );
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    foreach ( $sub_categories as $sub_category ){
        $links=get_category_link( $sub_category->term_id );
        ?>
<li>    <?php   
        echo '<label><a href='.$links.'><input type="checkbox" id="type-'. $sub_category->name . '" rel="'. $sub_category->name . '">'. $sub_category->name .'</a>'. '</label>';
?>
</li>
<?php
////////////////////////
$sub_arg = array(
        'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
        'child_of'        => $sub_category->term_id, // get child categories
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        //'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hierarchical'  => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    );

    $su_categories = get_categories( $sub_arg );
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    foreach ( $su_categories as $su_category ){
        $cat_link=get_category_link( $su_category->term_id );
        ?>
<li>    <?php   
        echo '<label><a href='.$links.'><input type="checkbox" id="type-'. $su_category->name . '" rel="'. $su_category->name . '">'. $su_category->name .'</a>'. '</label>';
?>
</li>
<?php
    }

//////////////////////////////
    }
?>
</ul>
<?php
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below code

   $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
      $orderby      = 'name';  
      $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
      $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
      $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
      $title        = '';  
      $empty        = 0;

      $args = array(
             'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
             'orderby'      => $orderby,
             'show_count'   => $show_count,
             'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
             'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
             'title_li'     => $title,
             'hide_empty'   => $empty
      );
     $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
     foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
            $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
            echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

            $args2 = array(
                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                    'child_of'     => 0,
                    'parent'       => $category_id,
                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                    'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty
            );
            $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
            if($sub_cats) {
                foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                    echo  $sub_category->name ;
                }   
            }
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This shortcode in your Place:-[woocommerce_nested_categories1]

Add this code in your function.php:-

```
function woocommerce_nested_categories() {
  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
      $orderby      = 'name';  
      $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
      $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
      $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
      $title        = '';  
      $empty        = 0;
      $args = array(
             'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
             'orderby'      => $orderby,
             'show_count'   => $show_count,
             'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
             'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
             'title_li'     => $title,
             'hide_empty'   => $empty
      );
     $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
     echo'<div class="outer-nested-woo-catg"><ul>';
     foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
            $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
            echo '<br /><li><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a></li>';

            $args2 = array(
                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                    'child_of'     => 0,
                    'parent'       => $category_id,
                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                    'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty
            );
            $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
            if($sub_cats) {
                echo'<ul>';
                foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {

                    echo  '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($sub_category->slug,'product_cat').'">'.$sub_category->name.'</a></li>' ;

                      $args3 = array(
                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                    'child_of'     => 1,
                    'parent'       => $sub_category->term_id,
                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                    'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty
            );

                 $sub_cats2=   get_categories( $args3 );

                    if($sub_cats2){
                         echo'<ul>';
                        foreach($sub_cats2 as $sub_category2) {
                              echo  '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($sub_category2->slug,'product_cat').'">'.$sub_category2->name.'</a></li>' ;
                                     $args4 = array(
                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                    'child_of'     => 1,
                    'parent'       => $sub_category2->term_id,
                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                    'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty
            );
                   $sub_cats3=   get_categories( $args4 );

                    if($sub_cats3){
                        echo'<ul>'; 
                        foreach($sub_cats3 as $sub_category3) {
                           echo  '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($sub_category3->slug,'product_cat').'">'.$sub_category3->name.'</a></li>' ;

                            $args5 = array(
                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                    'child_of'     => 1,
                    'parent'       => $sub_category3->term_id,
                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                    'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty
            );
                 $sub_cats4=   get_categories( $args5 );           
                     if($sub_cats4) {
              echo'<ul>'; 
                foreach($sub_cats4 as $sub_category4) {

                    echo  '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($sub_category4->slug,'product_cat').'">'.$sub_category4->name.'</a></li>' ;
                }        
                             echo'</ul>'; 
               }
              }
               echo'</ul>'; 

                    }
                        }
                     echo'</ul>'; 
                    }

                }   
                 echo'</ul>'; 
            }
        }       
    }

    echo'</ul></div>';
}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_nested_categories1', 'woocommerce_nested_categories');
```